# redirection to another adress depending of the visitors country

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, geolocation

I have a website that hosts 2 websites, one for international users and one for chinese users.
I want the visitor to be redirected to one of those 2 website depending of his country.
I've been searching on the net for a solution, and I'm using http://www.geobytes.com/GeoDirection.htm

here is the code I'm using :

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://gd.geobytes.com/Gd?after=-1"></script>
<script language="javascript">
if(typeof(sGeobytesLocationCode)!="undefined"&&sGeobytesLocationCode.indexOf('CN')==0)
{
    document.write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=http://www.SomeDomain.com'>");
}
</script>
```

it works fine, but when first visiting the international website, it starts loading, and the redirect if my visitor is chinese...
do you know a way of changing this ?
first detect the visitor country, then display the website if he is intenational, or redirect if he is chinese ?

thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Looks like you need a server side solution. Based on IP address or browser language setting?

Comment: @JvdBerg, do you have more information about your solutions ? would help, thanks

Comment: It depends on how your server side looks like. Node.js? php/apache? Other?

Comment: Are you looking for redirection based on visitor's location? http://ip2location.com/free/visitor-redirection